# ffmpeg using timestamp images only during duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to generate video from timestamped images. Here is the  command I use to generate a video from set of images:

```
ffmpeg  -f image2 -ts_from_file 2 -i './%*.jpeg' -vf fps=20   './video.avi'
```

The options ts_from_file is to generate video using timesramped image at nanosecond precision. The output framerate will be at 20Hz. I want to generate on 90 secondes of video from my set to images. 
That is to say, I want to use only a part of images corresponding to only 90 seconds.

Is there a way to add that setting in ffmpeg command or should I remove manually images which timestamped are older than desired duration?

Edit:

I finally do it in two steps. The first step I remove old files and then I use ffmpeg command to generate video from images with timestamp in nanosecond.

Comment: Just add `-t 90` as an output option.

Comment: Thank you indeed it works. What is in the created video? The bgenning of set of images or the end?  How could I specify that?

Comment: Since you have a wildcard glob `*` in your input string, the file order is based on how the system's glob function populates the array. It is usually the first set of images.

Comment: I try to build a simple command to do that. find . -name '*.jpeg'  -newermt '-1500000 seconds' | sort -nr | 'something_command' | ffmpeg  -f image2pipe -ts_from_file 2 -i './image_%04d.jpeg' -vf fps=20   './video.mp4'. But I don't know what to replace 'something_command'